# CFtpConnection GetFile error timeout

Tags: mfc, ftp

I have a program which downloads files using ftp connection to local directory. The local directory is created on program start and deleted upon exiting. Directory is used as temporary place for storing downloaded files and is created using

> GetTempPath()

Recently one of users reported that operation (GetFile()) hangs with error code 12002 (‘time out’). No one else reported this though, so my question is can UAC be blamed for not allowing files to be copied in temp folder especially if user isn’t administrator. The MSDN states that ‘GetTempPath()’:

> checks for the existence of environment variables in the following
>   order and uses the first path found:
>   1.    The path specified by the TMP environment variable.
>   2.    The path specified by the TEMP environment variable.
>   3.    The path specified by the USERPROFILE environment variable.
>   4.    The Windows directory. Note that the function does not verify that the path exists, nor does it test to see if the current process has
>   any kind of **access rights** to the path.

What is suggested way for dealing with temp folders/files if it can’t be done like this.
Thanks in advance